# Typescript : Check for words in a string

Tags: javascript, typescript

There are many options in javascript, but are there any options in typescript to do the find words in a given string:

*Eg*:

For the list: `['Mr', 'Mrs', 'FM.', 'Sir']` and a string called `'Sir FM. Sam Manekshaw'`. I have the words '*Sir*' and '*FM*.' present, hence needs to be assigned to a string and the remaining parts of the string assigned to another string. i.e:

```
a = Sir FM.
b = Sam Manekshaw
```

**NOTE**: It should validate only full words and not a substring.

**UPDATE**:
*What I tried:*

```
var tempPrefixList = ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'FM.', 'Sir'];
var firstName = "Sir FM. Sam Manekshaw";

var prefixSearchExp = new RegExp(tempPrefixList.join("|"),"gi");
if(firstName && prefixSearchExp.test(firstName)) {
    console.log("Caught");
    var requestFirstNameSplit = firstName?.split(" ");
    console.log("Prefix: " + requestFirstNameSplit[0]);
    console.log("First name: " + requestFirstNameSplit[1]);
}
```

But this considers only if the name has one Prefix. And also, has only one name in firstName. Eg: `Sir Sam`. But doesn't work for the example I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Options in JavaScript can also be used in TypeScript.

Comment: typescript is a superset of javascript. Everything which works in javascript works in typescript.

Comment: You may have forgotten to ask a question... Stack overflow is not a coding service where you drop in your requirements and get out some code. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Please find the UPDATE in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```js
class PersonDetails {
  formOfAddress: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(formOfAddress: string, name: string) {
    this.formOfAddress = formOfAddress;
    this.name = name;
  }

  get fullName(): string {
    return [this.formOfAddress, this.name].join(' ');
  }
}

function extractPersonDetailsFromFullName(fullName: string): PersonDetails {
  const formOfAddresses = ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'FM.', 'Sir'];

  let usedFormOfAddresses = [];

  const wordsInName = fullName.split(' ').filter((x) => x);
  for (const word of wordsInName ?? []) {
    if (formOfAddresses.filter((foa) => foa == word).length == 1) {
      usedFormOfAddresses.push(word);
    }
  }

  const formOfAddress = usedFormOfAddresses.join(' ');

  return new PersonDetails(
    formOfAddress,
    fullName.substr(formOfAddress.length).trim()
  );
}

const testNames = ['Sir FM. Sam Manekshaw', 'Mr Tom'];

for (const testName of testNames) {
  const personDetails = extractPersonDetailsFromFullName(testName);
  appDiv.innerHTML +=
    testName +
    ' => <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
    JSON.stringify(personDetails) +
    '<br><br>';
}
```

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-iyk3ul?file=index.ts

If you don't want to use the implementation with the separate function and object, you can use the following code:

```js
const fullName = 'Sir FM. Sam Manekshaw';

const formOfAddresses = ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'FM.', 'Sir'];

let formOfAddressParts = [];
let nameParts = [];

const wordsInName = fullName.split(' ').filter((x) => x);
for (const word of wordsInName ?? []) {
  if (formOfAddresses.filter((foa) => foa == word).length == 1) {
    formOfAddressParts.push(word);
  } else {
    nameParts.push(word);
  }
}

let formOfAddress = formOfAddressParts.join(' ');
let name = nameParts.join(' ');

console.log('formOfAddress: ', formOfAddress);
console.log('name: ', name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kevin. Your code is throwing `Object is possibly undefined` for `wordsInName` in `for` loop. Sorry that I am new to typescript and need help on this.

Comment: I change the loop definition now to `for (const word of (wordsInName ?? []))`. It is a shortcut, you can also surround the loop if an if statement where the condition is, that wordsInName is not undefined.

Comment: @Mike, was this the solution or do you still have compiling errors?

Comment: No Kevin, this didn't work. For my input with `Mr Tom` as fullName, the formOfAddress was populated as `Mr Tom` and name is populated as `null`.

Comment: @Mike, check https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-iyk3ul?file=index.ts and the code above, then you have your working example. :)

Comment: You're right man! Turns out that the `formOfAddresses` list which I had initialized had all caps. And my request payload had init caps and it hence the comparison was not proper !

Comment: Kevin, while adding the formOfAddress to the array, can we tweak it to remove that formOfAddress from the full name as well?

Comment: What do you mean? With the implementation above, you get a `PersonDetails`-object for every name. It has the properties `formOfAddress` and `name`. Each just contain the part it is named like (name is without formOfAddress). But the object also have a getter to merge the both to `fullName`. :)

Comment: @Mike I think I know what you mean. Maybe you want to have some inline implementation without the function and the object. I added another, smaller implementation to my answer where you get the form of address and the name in two separate variables.